# All drives mount read-only except primary ubuntu drive

Tags: read-only

Fresh Install 20.04. I dual boot with Window 10. When I boot to Ubuntu, my Windows HDD and other NTFS/exfat drives mount read-only. I tried modifying fstab, but no change. Is there any way to make these drives writable?

Comment: Are these all NTFS partitioned? Do you dual-boot with Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This question has been asked many times. Most probably you just have to uncheck the "turn on fast startup" option in Windows.
Navigate to `Control Panel --> Power Option --> Choose what power buttons do --> Change settings that are currently unavailable` Then uncheck turn on fast startup.