# I can't write to my hard disk

Tags: permissions, read-only

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 and after doing a regular system update I don't have writing access to my second HDD (NTFS). I've tried `sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point` and that gives me r/w access but this time throws no such dir when I try to create a folder in that HDD even though it looks like it is mounted.What could I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS & release, but usually if a RW volume flips RO it's to prevent data loss because logical flaws were detected and a `fsck` needs to be performed. Check your logs, and please provide OS & release details, and specific details for specific advice.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details I use Ubuntu 20.04.1 and the HDD that I mentioned is NTFS

Comment: Check messages when you mount, but a NTFS file-system maybe mounted RO because it's unclean/dirty (ie. is missing data because it was last used by a hibernated/fast-boot windows system that stored part of the file-system inside the fast-boot/hibernation recovery file; thus it's preventing changes that may cause data-loss due to incomplete state).  Either way messages/logs are your clue (mount via CLI/shell allows you to see messages straight away, if you don't like looking in logs).

Comment: Ah thank you so much apparently It was an unclean file system
 `The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.`

Answer (score 0):

In case you have Windows 10 or Windows 8 on the 2nd HDD, check this link: [All drives mount read-only except primary ubuntu drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/1252677/942479).

Windows is blocking the disks: you have to boot in Windows and uncheck "Turn on fast startup"